# Why Doesn't HTML Use A Coordinate-Based Format?

Tags: html

Why doesn't it? Also, is there a co-ordinate-based alternative to HTML?

I.E. An img tag would be;

`<img src="cats.jpg" x="100" y="200">`

Is it just efficiency?

Comment: It is really hard to understand what are you asking, what do you mean by coordinate-based? what do x and y do in your img tag? what's the unit of x and y?

Comment: @Sang I meant literal coordinates on the x and y axis. But don't worry, Liam got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it has CSS and the Box Model instead. They are simple, very flexible and allow greater control than using just co-ordinates. You can use pixel values and the 'absolute' positioning attribute to get something similar to what you would like but there is many scenarios where just this is not ideal.